# Why doesn't AngularJS detect checkboxes when using Bootstrap plugin?

Tags: angularjs

I'm using the jQuery plugin "Bootstrap Checkboxes", and also AngularJS framework.
At first the plugin is loaded to the page with checkboxes inside the Angular controller:

```
<input type="checkbox" required="" value="19" ng-model="formData.type[19]" ng-click="setCheckbox(19)" name="type[]">
```

When I click any checkbox nothing happens, so function `setCheckbox(19)` is not called.
Why Angular does not see `ng-model` from the jQuery plugin?

Comment: Can we see you controller?

Comment: Can you post your code in Plunker or JSFiddle?